# Handling javascript events of a NVD3 chart

Tags: javascript, eclipse, d3.js, swt, nvd3.js

I am integrating NVD3 into an Eclipse SWT based application and I would like to delegate Javascript events of the chart to the embedding Java code *(publishEventJavaSide and logToJavaContainer are [BrowserFunctions](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/BrowserFunction.html))*. This works perfectly for redirecting `elementClick` event. The code for `elementClick` looks something like this:

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
    try {
        function generateChart() {
            return nv.models.discreteBarChart()
                .x(function (d) {
                    return d.name
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return d.value
                })
                .staggerLabels(false)
                .tooltips(true)
                .showValues(true);
        }

        var chart = generateChart();
        chart.dispatch.on('elementClick', function (e) {
            publishEventJavaSide('elementClick', JSON.stringify(e, jsonCensor));
        });
        logToJavaContainer('TRACE', 'The JSON Data to be displayed in the chart sent by the server is the following: \n' + JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(generateData()), null, 4));
        d3.select('#chart svg').datum(JSON.parse(generateData())).transition().duration(500).call(chart);
        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
        return chart;
    } catch (e) {
        logToJavaContainer('ERROR', 'Error while running chart creation function' + JSON.stringify(e, ["message", "arguments", "type", "name", "stack"]));
    }
});
```

After browsing the source of [DiscreteBarChart](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/13d5dec998e554389a0b214afd3891ca831b06f3/src/models/discreteBar.js) I supposed, that any of `chartClick`, `elementDblClick`, `elementMouseover`, `elementMouseout` should work like `elementClick` works. But actually none of them are working. If I try the following code for `elementDblClick` *(only the name of the event is changed)*:

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
    try {
        function generateChart() {
            return nv.models.discreteBarChart()
                .x(function (d) {
                    return d.name
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return d.value
                })
                .staggerLabels(false)
                .tooltips(true)
                .showValues(true);
        }

        var chart = generateChart();
        chart.dispatch.on('elementDblClick', function (e) {
            publishEventJavaSide('elementDblClick', JSON.stringify(e, jsonCensor));
        });
        logToJavaContainer('TRACE', 'The JSON Data to be displayed in the chart sent by the server is the following: \n' + JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(generateData()), null, 4));
        d3.select('#chart svg').datum(JSON.parse(generateData())).transition().duration(500).call(chart);
        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
        return chart;
    } catch (e) {
        logToJavaContainer('ERROR', 'Error while running chart creation function' + JSON.stringify(e, ["message", "arguments", "type", "name", "stack"]));
    }
});
```

It does not work. The wrapping catch catches the following error coming from the line `chart.dispatch.on('elementDblClick', function (e)`:

```
Error while running chart creation function{
    "message":"Cannot call method 'on' of undefined",
    "name":"TypeError",
    "stack":
        "TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
            at d3_dispatch.on (http://127.0.0.1:10080/chart:1132:78)
            at Object.eval [as generate] (eval 
            at <anonymous> (eval 
            at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:10080/rwt-resources/rap-client.js:54872:27)), <anonymous>:12:16)
            at http://127.0.0.1:10080/chart:10440:21"
    }
```

The reference `chart.dispatch` is surely not undefined *(I checked with an alert, and it is `Object`)*, and the thing comes from the d3 code somewhere. I am also pretty sure, that my integration has nothing to do with it. I could find only examples with `elementClick` sadly.

I am not Javascript nor D3 or NVD3 expert, please be patient with me in the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
chart.discretebar.dispatch.on("elementClick", function(e) {
    console.log('elementClick', e);
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Only chartClick does not work, but it actually does not disturb me too much. How did you know this? How can it be seen from sourcecode?

Comment: I see. "nv.models.discreteBar = function() { ..." from the sourcecode. Ok.